# Problem with screen autorotation - systemd hwdb

Tags: systemd, udev, gnu-screen, mutter

I want to get my Spectre x360 screen rotation to work.
`iio-sensor-proxy` correctly find the normal orientation, but when I rotate the laptop, it doesn't register any movement.

I found somewhere that setting a rules for the accelerometer would make it work so I created `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-sensor-local.hwdb`. Here the content:

```
#Entry for screen rotation
#device number /dev/iio-device0.0002
#devive modalias platform:HID-SENSOR-200086
#String formats: 
# sensor:modalias:<parent device modalias>:dmi:<dmi string>
#To load the new rules execute (as root):
#   systemd-hwdb update
#   udevadm trigger -v -p DEVNAME=/dev/iio:device0.0002
# where /dev/iio:deviceXXX is the device in question.

#Full dmi dmi:bvnAMI:bvrF.38:bd12/08/2022:br15.38:efr56.50:svnHP:pnHPSpectrex360Convertible13-ae0xx:pvr:rvnHP:rn83B9:rvr56.50:cvnHP:ct31:cvrChassisVersion:sku3DM09EA#ABZ:

sensor:modalias:platform:HID-SENSOR-2000*:dmi:bvnAMI:bvrF.38:bd12/08/2022:br15.38:efr56.50:svnHP:pnHPSpectrex360Convertible13-ae0xx:pvr:rvnHP:rn83B9:rvr56.50:cvnHP:ct31:cvrChassisVersion:sku3DM09EA#ABZ
ACCEL_LOCATION=display
sensor:modalias:acpi:/dev/iio-device*:dmi:bvnAMI:bvrF.38:bd12/08/2022:br15.38:efr56.50:svnHP:pnHPSpectrex360Convertible13-ae0xx:pvr:rvnHP:rn83B9:rvr56.50:cvnHP:ct31:cvrChassisVersion:sku3DM09EA#ABZ
ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=0, 1, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1
```

but it doesn't work.

Am I configuring something wrong?